# Optimizing the sum of quadratic forms linked by orthogonality constraints

Tags: matrices, optimization, symmetric-matrices, qcqp, stiefel-manifolds

I am looking to find a qualitative solution to the optimization problem:

$$\text{min}_{\{\mathbf{u}_i\}_i}\quad\sum_i \mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{M}_i\mathbf{u}_i \\
\text{s.t.}\quad \mathbf{u}_i^T\mathbf{u}_j = \delta_{ij}, \quad \forall i,j$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta (so $\mathbf{u}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are orthonormal) and all $\mathbf{M}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ can be considered positive definite and symmetric.

My trouble here is that there a **different** matrices in each summand.
If they all would be the same, the solutions should just be the eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalues. Otherwise, if I wouldn't require the vectors to be orthogonal, the solutions would correspond to each smallest eigenvectors of each individual matrix $\mathbf{M}_i$.

I 'd be very grateful for any pointer -- for example, is there a name for these kind of problems? -- and sincerely hope that this is not too stupid of a problem.

Comment: How many $\bf u$'s do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I have some references if you want:

- [Extrema of sums of heterogeneous quadratic forms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379597002309)
- [On Minimization of Sums of Heterogeneous Quadratic Functions on Stiefel Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-5284-7_12)